# Unable to implement authorization in spring security

Tags: java, authentication, spring-security

The user is not authorized when entering the correct login (in my case, mail) and password.
I tried to check what the error is through a breakpoint, but it doesn't even enter `loadUserByUsername`.
Registration is working properly. Due to the fact that I tried not to use the `WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter`,
it turned out that I could not find very much information. Lack of experience.I set a breakpoint in the `authenticate()` method, I expected that I would see the login and password there, but the principal = "" and credentials = "123" (I used the values dm@gmail.com and password 123 as input).I figured out the output of username in `authenticate ()`, in the form there was name = "email".

Following the actions of the program, I noticed that in the `UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken` class it enters the `UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken(Object principal, Object credentials)` method, but not in `UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken(Object principal, Object credentials, Collection<? extends GrantedAuthentication> authorities)` where authorization would be set to true. Based on this, I think there is an error in the user class where `getAuthorities` returns a collection (it was assumed that one user can only be assigned one role)

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebSecurity
public class WebSecurityConfig {
    @Autowired
    private UserService userService;

        protected void configure(AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth) throws Exception {
        auth.userDetailsService(userService).passwordEncoder(bCryptPasswordEncoder());
    }

    @Bean
    public BCryptPasswordEncoder bCryptPasswordEncoder() {
        return new BCryptPasswordEncoder();
    }

    @Bean
    public SecurityFilterChain securityFilterChain(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception{
        http
                .authorizeHttpRequests((requests)->requests
                        .requestMatchers("/login","/static/**","/registration").permitAll()
                        .anyRequest().authenticated()
                )
                .formLogin((form)->form
                        .loginPage("/login")
                        .permitAll()
                )
                .logout((logout)->logout.permitAll());
        return http.build();
    }
}
```

...

```
@Configuration
public class MvcConfig implements WebMvcConfigurer {
    @Override
    public void addResourceHandlers(ResourceHandlerRegistry registry) {
        registry.addResourceHandler("/static/**")
                .addResourceLocations("classpath:/static/");
    }
    public void addViewControllers(ViewControllerRegistry registry){
        registry.addViewController("/main").setViewName("main");
        registry.addViewController("/").setViewName("main");
        registry.addViewController("/login").setViewName("login");
        registry.addViewController("/registration").setViewName("registration");
    }
}
```

...

```
@Controller
@RequiredArgsConstructor
public class RegistrationController {
    @Autowired
    private UserService userService;
    @GetMapping("/registration")
    public String showRegistrationForm(Model model) {
        model.addAttribute("user", new User());
        return "registration";
    }
    @GetMapping("/login")
    String login(){
        return "login";
    }
    @PostMapping("/registration")
    public String processRegistrationForm(@ModelAttribute("user") @Valid User registrationForm,
                                          BindingResult bindingResult, Model model) {
        if (bindingResult.hasErrors()) {
            return "registration";
        }
        if (!registrationForm.getPassword().equals(registrationForm.getPassword())) {
            model.addAttribute("errorMessage", "Пароли не совпадают");
            return "registration";
        }
        if (!userService.saveUser(registrationForm)){
            model.addAttribute("errorMessage", "Пользователь с таким именем уже существует");
            return "registration";
        }
        return "redirect:/login";
    }
}
```

...

```
@Service
public class UserService implements UserDetailsService {
@PersistenceContext
    private EntityManager em;
@Autowired
    UserRepository userRepository;
    @Autowired
    private RoleRepository roleRepository;

    private BCryptPasswordEncoder bCryptPasswordEncoder;

    @Override
    public UserDetails loadUserByUsername(String email) throws UsernameNotFoundException {
        User user = userRepository.findByEmail(email);

        if(user == null){
            throw new UsernameNotFoundException("User not found");
        }
        return user;
    }
    public User findByUser(String name){
        return userRepository.findByEmail(name);
    }
    public List<User> allUser(){
        return userRepository.findAll();
    }
    public boolean saveUser(User user){
        User userFromDb = userRepository.findByEmail(user.getUsername());
        Role userRole = roleRepository.findByName("ROLE_ADMIN");
        String email = user.getEmail();
        if(userRole == null){
            userRole = roleRepository.findByName("ROLE_USER");
            if(userRole == null)    {
                Role role = new Role("ROLE_USER");
            roleRepository.save(role);
            }
        }
        if(userFromDb != null) {
            return false;
        }

        user.setRole(userRole);
        user.setPassword(bCryptPasswordEncoder.encode(user.getPassword()));
        userRepository.save(user);
        return true;
    }
    public boolean deleteUser(Long userId){
        if(userRepository.findById(userId).isPresent()){
            userRepository.deleteById(userId);
            return true;
        }
        return false;
    }
    public List<User> usergtList(List idMin){
        return em.createQuery("SELECT u FROM User u WHERE u.id > :paramId", User.class)
                .setParameter("paramId", idMin).getResultList();
    }
}
```

```
@Entity
@Data
@Table(name = "user")
public class User implements UserDetails {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    @Column(name = "id")
    private Long id;
    @Column(name = "firstName")
    private String firstName;
    @Column(name = "lastName")
    private String lastName;
    @Column(name = "email")
    private String email;
    @Column(name = "password")
    private String password;
    @Transient
    private String confirmPassword;
    @ManyToOne(cascade = CascadeType.REFRESH,fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    private Role role;

    @Override
    public Collection<? extends GrantedAuthority> getAuthorities() {
        return Collections.singletonList(new SimpleGrantedAuthority(role.getName()));
    }

    @Override
    public String getUsername(){
        return email;
    }
    @Override
    public boolean isAccountNonExpired() {
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean isAccountNonLocked() {
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean isCredentialsNonExpired() {
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean isEnabled() {
        return false;
    }
}
```

...

```
    @Entity
@Data
@Table(name = "role")
public class Role implements GrantedAuthority {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    @Column(name = "id")
    private Long id;
    @Column(name = "name")
    private String name;
    @Transient
    @OneToMany(cascade = CascadeType.ALL, fetch = FetchType.EAGER, mappedBy = "role")
    private Set<User> users;
    public Role(){

    }
    public Role(String name){
        this.name = name;
    }

    @Override
    public String getAuthority() {
        return getName();
    }

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }
}
```

...

```
2023-04-12T17:28:44.303+03:00  INFO 23948 --- [main] com.doc.point.PointApplication           : Starting PointApplication using Java 18.0.2 with PID 23948 (C:\Users\Goldo\OneDrive\Рабочий стол\TestSequrity\point\target\classes started by Goldo in C:\Users\Goldo\OneDrive\Рабочий стол\TestSequrity)
2023-04-12T17:28:44.304+03:00  INFO 23948 --- [main] com.doc.point.PointApplication           : No active profile set, falling back to 1 default profile: "default"
2023-04-12T17:28:44.792+03:00  INFO 23948 --- [main] .s.d.r.c.RepositoryConfigurationDelegate : Bootstrapping Spring Data JPA repositories in DEFAULT mode.
2023-04-12T17:28:44.827+03:00  INFO 23948 --- [main] .s.d.r.c.RepositoryConfigurationDelegate : Finished Spring Data repository scanning in 29 ms. Found 2 JPA repository interfaces.
2023-04-12T17:28:45.135+03:00  INFO 23948 --- [main] o.s.b.w.embedded.tomcat.TomcatWebServer  : Tomcat initialized with port(s): 8080 (http)
2023-04-12T17:28:45.141+03:00  INFO 23948 --- [main] o.apache.catalina.core.StandardService   : Starting service [Tomcat]
2023-04-12T17:28:45.141+03:00  INFO 23948 --- [main] o.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngine    : Starting Servlet engine: [Apache Tomcat/10.1.7]
2023-04-12T17:28:45.199+03:00  INFO 23948 --- [main] o.a.c.c.C.[Tomcat].[localhost].[/]       : Initializing Spring embedded WebApplicationContext
2023-04-12T17:28:45.199+03:00  INFO 23948 --- [main] w.s.c.ServletWebServerApplicationContext : Root WebApplicationContext: initialization completed in 871 ms
2023-04-12T17:28:45.281+03:00 DEBUG 23948 --- [main] o.s.w.f.ServerHttpObservationFilter      : Filter 'serverHttpObservationFilter' configured for use
2023-04-12T17:28:45.338+03:00  INFO 23948 --- [main] o.hibernate.jpa.internal.util.LogHelper  : HHH000204: Processing PersistenceUnitInfo [name: default]
2023-04-12T17:28:45.370+03:00  INFO 23948 --- [main] org.hibernate.Version                    : HHH000412: Hibernate ORM core version 6.1.7.Final
2023-04-12T17:28:45.538+03:00  INFO 23948 --- [main] com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariDataSource       : HikariPool-1 - Starting...
2023-04-12T17:28:45.620+03:00  INFO 23948 --- [main] com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.HikariPool        : HikariPool-1 - Added connection com.mysql.cj.jdbc.ConnectionImpl@37a3ec27
2023-04-12T17:28:45.621+03:00  INFO 23948 --- [main] com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariDataSource       : HikariPool-1 - Start completed.
2023-04-12T17:28:45.650+03:00  INFO 23948 --- [main] SQL dialect                              : HHH000400: Using dialect: org.hibernate.dialect.MySQLDialect
2023-04-12T17:28:46.107+03:00  INFO 23948 --- [main] o.h.e.t.j.p.i.JtaPlatformInitiator       : HHH000490: Using JtaPlatform implementation: [org.hibernate.engine.transaction.jta.platform.internal.NoJtaPlatform]
2023-04-12T17:28:46.113+03:00  INFO 23948 --- [main] j.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean : Initialized JPA EntityManagerFactory for persistence unit 'default'
2023-04-12T17:28:46.321+03:00  WARN 23948 --- [main] JpaBaseConfiguration$JpaWebConfiguration : spring.jpa.open-in-view is enabled by default. Therefore, database queries may be performed during view rendering. Explicitly configure spring.jpa.open-in-view to disable this warning
2023-04-12T17:28:46.404+03:00 DEBUG 23948 --- [main] s.w.s.m.m.a.RequestMappingHandlerMapping : 5 mappings in 'requestMappingHandlerMapping'
2023-04-12T17:28:46.407+03:00 DEBUG 23948 --- [main] o.s.w.s.handler.SimpleUrlHandlerMapping  : Patterns [/, /main, /login, /registration] in 'viewControllerHandlerMapping'
2023-04-12T17:28:46.445+03:00 DEBUG 23948 --- [main] o.s.w.s.handler.SimpleUrlHandlerMapping  : Patterns [/webjars/**, /**, /static/**] in 'resourceHandlerMapping'
2023-04-12T17:28:46.509+03:00  INFO 23948 --- [main] o.s.b.a.e.web.EndpointLinksResolver      : Exposing 1 endpoint(s) beneath base path '/actuator'
2023-04-12T17:28:46.536+03:00  INFO 23948 --- [main] o.s.s.web.DefaultSecurityFilterChain     : Will secure any request with [org.springframework.security.web.session.DisableEncodeUrlFilter@3bdc8975, org.springframework.security.web.context.request.async.WebAsyncManagerIntegrationFilter@27ea552d, org.springframework.security.web.context.SecurityContextHolderFilter@3d67e3d3, org.springframework.security.web.header.HeaderWriterFilter@1c76b2fe, org.springframework.security.web.csrf.CsrfFilter@4197e859, org.springframework.security.web.authentication.logout.LogoutFilter@1d7f0cd0, org.springframework.security.web.authentication.UsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter@198a0416, org.springframework.security.web.savedrequest.RequestCacheAwareFilter@795949fb, org.springframework.security.web.servletapi.SecurityContextHolderAwareRequestFilter@75caecf7, org.springframework.security.web.authentication.AnonymousAuthenticationFilter@7a57c5d9, org.springframework.security.web.access.ExceptionTranslationFilter@5abc488d, org.springframework.security.web.access.intercept.AuthorizationFilter@5058fefb]
2023-04-12T17:28:46.544+03:00  WARN 23948 --- [main] o.s.security.core.userdetails.User       : User.withDefaultPasswordEncoder() is considered unsafe for production and is only intended for sample applications.
2023-04-12T17:28:46.640+03:00 DEBUG 23948 --- [main] s.w.s.m.m.a.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter : ControllerAdvice beans: 0 @ModelAttribute, 0 @InitBinder, 1 RequestBodyAdvice, 1 ResponseBodyAdvice
2023-04-12T17:28:46.663+03:00 DEBUG 23948 --- [main] .m.m.a.ExceptionHandlerExceptionResolver : ControllerAdvice beans: 0 @ExceptionHandler, 1 ResponseBodyAdvice
2023-04-12T17:28:46.804+03:00  INFO 23948 --- [main] o.s.b.w.embedded.tomcat.TomcatWebServer  : Tomcat started on port(s): 8080 (http) with context path ''
2023-04-12T17:28:46.812+03:00  INFO 23948 --- [main] com.doc.point.PointApplication           : Started PointApplication in 2.766 seconds (process running for 3.161)
2023-04-12T17:28:47.382+03:00  INFO 23948 --- [RMI TCP Connection(3)-26.13.229.161] o.a.c.c.C.[Tomcat].[localhost].[/]       : Initializing Spring DispatcherServlet 'dispatcherServlet'
2023-04-12T17:28:47.382+03:00  INFO 23948 --- [RMI TCP Connection(3)-26.13.229.161] o.s.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet        : Initializing Servlet 'dispatcherServlet'
2023-04-12T17:28:47.382+03:00 DEBUG 23948 --- [RMI TCP Connection(3)-26.13.229.161] o.s.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet        : Detected StandardServletMultipartResolver
2023-04-12T17:28:47.382+03:00 DEBUG 23948 --- [RMI TCP Connection(3)-26.13.229.161] o.s.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet        : Detected AcceptHeaderLocaleResolver
2023-04-12T17:28:47.382+03:00 DEBUG 23948 --- [RMI TCP Connection(3)-26.13.229.161] o.s.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet        : Detected FixedThemeResolver
2023-04-12T17:28:47.383+03:00 DEBUG 23948 --- [RMI TCP Connection(3)-26.13.229.161] o.s.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet        : Detected org.springframework.web.servlet.view.DefaultRequestToViewNameTranslator@2ca464bb
2023-04-12T17:28:47.383+03:00 DEBUG 23948 --- [RMI TCP Connection(3)-26.13.229.161] o.s.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet        : Detected org.springframework.web.servlet.support.SessionFlashMapManager@5de14222
2023-04-12T17:28:47.383+03:00 DEBUG 23948 --- [RMI TCP Connection(3)-26.13.229.161] o.s.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet        : enableLoggingRequestDetails='false': request parameters and headers will be masked to prevent unsafe logging of potentially sensitive data
2023-04-12T17:28:47.383+03:00  INFO 23948 --- [RMI TCP Connection(3)-26.13.229.161] o.s.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet        : Completed initialization in 1 ms
2023-04-12T17:28:55.218+03:00 DEBUG 23948 --- [http-nio-8080-exec-1] o.s.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet        : GET "/login?error", parameters={masked}
2023-04-12T17:28:55.224+03:00 DEBUG 23948 --- [http-nio-8080-exec-1] s.w.s.m.m.a.RequestMappingHandlerMapping : Mapped to com.doc.point.Controllers.RegistrationController#login()
2023-04-12T17:28:55.234+03:00 DEBUG 23948 --- [http-nio-8080-exec-1] o.s.w.s.v.ContentNegotiatingViewResolver : Selected 'text/html' given [text/html, application/xhtml+xml, image/avif, image/webp, image/apng, application/xml;q=0.9, */*;q=0.8, application/signed-exchange;v=b3;q=0.7]
2023-04-12T17:28:55.448+03:00 DEBUG 23948 --- [http-nio-8080-exec-1] o.s.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet        : Completed 200 OK
2023-04-12T17:28:55.464+03:00 DEBUG 23948 --- [http-nio-8080-exec-2] o.s.w.s.handler.SimpleUrlHandlerMapping  : Mapped to ResourceHttpRequestHandler [classpath [static/]]
2023-04-12T17:28:55.464+03:00 DEBUG 23948 --- [http-nio-8080-exec-2] o.s.w.s.handler.SimpleUrlHandlerMapping  : Mapped to ResourceHttpRequestHandler [classpath [static/]]
2023-04-12T17:28:55.465+03:00 DEBUG 23948 --- [http-nio-8080-exec-2] o.s.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet        : GET "/static/css/styleSignIn.css", parameters={}
2023-04-12T17:28:55.465+03:00 DEBUG 23948 --- [http-nio-8080-exec-2] o.s.w.s.handler.SimpleUrlHandlerMapping  : Mapped to ResourceHttpRequestHandler [classpath [static/]]
2023-04-12T17:28:55.470+03:00 DEBUG 23948 --- [http-nio-8080-exec-2] o.s.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet        : Completed 200 OK
2023-04-12T17:29:00.149+03:00 DEBUG 23948 --- [http-nio-8080-exec-3] o.s.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet        : GET "/login", parameters={}
2023-04-12T17:29:00.149+03:00 DEBUG 23948 --- [http-nio-8080-exec-3] s.w.s.m.m.a.RequestMappingHandlerMapping : Mapped to com.doc.point.Controllers.RegistrationController#login()
2023-04-12T17:29:00.150+03:00 DEBUG 23948 --- [http-nio-8080-exec-3] o.s.w.s.v.ContentNegotiatingViewResolver : Selected 'text/html' given [text/html, application/xhtml+xml, image/avif, image/webp, image/apng, application/xml;q=0.9, */*;q=0.8, application/signed-exchange;v=b3;q=0.7]
2023-04-12T17:29:00.151+03:00 DEBUG 23948 --- [http-nio-8080-exec-3] o.s.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet        : Completed 200 OK
2023-04-12T17:29:00.170+03:00 DEBUG 23948 --- [http-nio-8080-exec-4] o.s.w.s.handler.SimpleUrlHandlerMapping  : Mapped to ResourceHttpRequestHandler [classpath [static/]]
2023-04-12T17:29:00.170+03:00 DEBUG 23948 --- [http-nio-8080-exec-4] o.s.w.s.handler.SimpleUrlHandlerMapping  : Mapped to ResourceHttpRequestHandler [classpath [static/]]
2023-04-12T17:29:00.170+03:00 DEBUG 23948 --- [http-nio-8080-exec-4] o.s.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet        : GET "/static/css/styleSignIn.css", parameters={}
2023-04-12T17:29:00.171+03:00 DEBUG 23948 --- [http-nio-8080-exec-4] o.s.w.s.handler.SimpleUrlHandlerMapping  : Mapped to ResourceHttpRequestHandler [classpath [static/]]
2023-04-12T17:29:00.173+03:00 DEBUG 23948 --- [http-nio-8080-exec-4] o.s.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet        : Completed 200 OK
2023-04-12T17:29:10.591+03:00 DEBUG 23948 --- [http-nio-8080-exec-6] o.s.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet        : GET "/login?error", parameters={masked}
2023-04-12T17:29:10.592+03:00 DEBUG 23948 --- [http-nio-8080-exec-6] s.w.s.m.m.a.RequestMappingHandlerMapping : Mapped to com.doc.point.Controllers.RegistrationController#login()
2023-04-12T17:29:10.593+03:00 DEBUG 23948 --- [http-nio-8080-exec-6] o.s.w.s.v.ContentNegotiatingViewResolver : Selected 'text/html' given [text/html, application/xhtml+xml, image/avif, image/webp, image/apng, application/xml;q=0.9, */*;q=0.8, application/signed-exchange;v=b3;q=0.7]
2023-04-12T17:29:10.594+03:00 DEBUG 23948 --- [http-nio-8080-exec-6] o.s.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet        : Completed 200 OK
2023-04-12T17:29:10.608+03:00 DEBUG 23948 --- [http-nio-8080-exec-7] o.s.w.s.handler.SimpleUrlHandlerMapping  : Mapped to ResourceHttpRequestHandler [classpath [static/]]
2023-04-12T17:29:10.609+03:00 DEBUG 23948 --- [http-nio-8080-exec-7] o.s.w.s.handler.SimpleUrlHandlerMapping  : Mapped to ResourceHttpRequestHandler [classpath [static/]]
2023-04-12T17:29:10.609+03:00 DEBUG 23948 --- [http-nio-8080-exec-7] o.s.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet        : GET "/static/css/styleSignIn.css", parameters={}
2023-04-12T17:29:10.609+03:00 DEBUG 23948 --- [http-nio-8080-exec-7] o.s.w.s.handler.SimpleUrlHandlerMapping  : Mapped to ResourceHttpRequestHandler [classpath [static/]]
2023-04-12T17:29:10.610+03:00 DEBUG 23948 --- [http-nio-8080-exec-7] o.s.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet        : Completed 200 OK
2023-04-12T17:29:18.288+03:00  INFO 23948 --- [SpringApplicationShutdownHook] j.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean : Closing JPA EntityManagerFactory for persistence unit 'default'
2023-04-12T17:29:18.289+03:00  INFO 23948 --- [SpringApplicationShutdownHook] com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariDataSource       : HikariPool-1 - Shutdown initiated...
2023-04-12T17:29:18.293+03:00  INFO 23948 --- [SpringApplicationShutdownHook] com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariDataSource       : HikariPool-1 - Shutdown completed.
```

...

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" xmlns:th="https://www.thymeleaf.org" lang="en">
<head>
  <title>Вход</title>
  <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8" />
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.2.3/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css">
  <link rel="script" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.2.3/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="static/css/styleSignIn.css">
</head>
<body class="text-center">
<div>
  <header>
    <a href="/" class="d-flex align-items-center mb-3 mb-md-0 me-md-auto link-body-emphasis text-decoration-none">
      <svg class="bi me-2" width="40" height="32"><use xlink:href="#bootstrap"/></svg>
      <span class="fs-4">Simple header</span>
    </a>

    <ul class="nav nav-pills">
      <li class="nav-item"><a href="#" class="nav-link active" aria-current="page">Home</a></li>
      <li class="nav-item"><a href="#" class="nav-link">Features</a></li>
      <li class="nav-item"><a href="#" class="nav-link">Pricing</a></li>
      <li class="nav-item"><a href="#" class="nav-link">FAQs</a></li>
      <li class="nav-item"><a href="#" class="nav-link">About</a></li>
    </ul>
  </header>
</div>
  <main class="form-signin w-100 m-auto">
    <form th:action="@{/login}" method="post">
      <h1 class="h3 mb-3 fw-normal">log in</h1>
      <div class="form-floating">
        <input type="email" class="form-control" id="floatingInput" name="username" placeholder="name@example.com">
        <label for="floatingInput">Email address</label>
      </div>
      <div class="form-floating">
        <input type="password" class="form-control" id="floatingPassword" name="password" placeholder="Password">
        <label for="floatingPassword">Password</label>
      </div>
      <div th:if="${param.error}">
        Invalid username and password.
      </div>
      <input type="hidden" name="_csrf" value="${_csrf.token}"/>
      <button class="w-100 btn btn-lg btn-primary" type="submit">Вход</button>
      <a th:href="@{/registration}">Registration</a>
      <p class="mt-2 mb-2 text-muted">©2023</p>
    </form>
  </main>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: @Z-100 it seems like yes, the default mechanism, although I can't be sure that I understand correctly.  outputs nothing to the console.  just sends back to login page with url: login?error

Comment: `@SpringBootApplication: exclude = SecurityAutoConfiguration.class` is not a good choice as this will disable the default security configurations that you get with proper security headers etc. Do not add this.

Comment: @Goldolov Your logs ar about loading the login page, but not about submitting username and password. So my guess is, your HTML page doesn't submit anything. Show your source code of your login page.

Comment: i dont see any `POST` to `/login` in the logs so what actually happens when you push the login button? is there any request being even made? have you looked in the F12 console of the browser?

Comment: @Toerktumlare There are no messages in the console, the conI did not find any information about the post request, which is strange. I traced the path through breakpoints, I saw that it takes the login and password and in one function it sets that it is not authenticated (perhaps because of the role)sole level is detailed.

Comment: You are giving us contradicting information. You say you dont find any information about the request in the browser, yet you say that you can debug with breakpoints in the backend. If there is no request from the frontend how can you debug the backend. This commentsection is getting too long. Stack overflow is not a forum. Good luck